# How to reset/recover password on Ascend/Lucent "SuperPipe 155" ISDN router

Tags: hardware, network

I am trying to set up a second-hand 1990s era Ascend/Lucent "SuperPipe 155" ISDN router for use with some of my 90s era computers, but I don't know the router's password and the instructions I found for resetting it to the system default are not working. Do any of you remember how this was done on this machine?

I tried the instructions in [this thread](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=407007) but they did not work. The NINDY (bootloader) code on my unit seems to be a bit different than described in that thread. The thread references an "EF" (erase flash) command, but that option does not show up in mine. The only similar option on mine is "EP" (menu description: erase program area).

Running EP does seem to erase the OS from the unit's flash memory; typing EF does nothing. After erasing the program area, I can install various versions of the OS using the DF command, but the configuration and password remain in place even after downgrading to 7.4.2 and then upgrading back to 9.1-144.1 or 9.1-144.3 as mentioned in the thread.

Do any of you remember working with these and have any other ideas I could try?

Comment: While there's a good chance that someone here has the desired information, you might want to try [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) in addition.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) and/or [Networkengineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) might be good places to ask, but I am not clear on the rules here concerning cross-posting, and didn't want to spam the question around too much.

Comment: You're right. Senseless cross posting is never welcome. Then again, this question is quite borderline on RC.SE. Not per se off topic, but as well not really main focus. Networking is as well a good place to find some admins/network engineers who have worked with that router back then.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't 100% sure about that either. The reason I thought this might be the best fit is that this equipment is so old that (I strongly assume) nobody actually uses it in production anymore, and the only reason I want to use it is because of nostalgia. I thought that might fit more with the retrocomputing topic than actual network engineering or system administration.

Comment: @Raffzahn Thanks for your edit to the question's title. For some reason, when I put the word "router" at the end of the title (as you added), the site would not let me post the question; I received a message saying "this looks like spam". I don't know why removing the word "router" made it pass the spam check, but I agree that the title is more self-explanatory with the word there.

Comment: The cross-posting isn't _great_, seeing as you're looking for the same answer. Make sure you go back to each question and post an answer if you get an answer on one site; that's the _minimum_ to do for cross-posting identical questions when you desire identical answers.

Comment: [Network Engineering question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/57583/56753).